# How to check if an activity is locked (app pinning) in android Lollipop

Tags: android-activity, task, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

I would like to know whether an activity is locked under app pinning in android 5.0 and above programatically. Please help me in this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Method to get if the activity in lock task mode.
activityManager.isInLockTaskMode() API is deprecated in API level 23. Use the method activityManager.getLockTaskModeState()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLockTaskModeState()

```
public boolean isAppInLockTaskMode() {
    ActivityManager activityManager;

    activityManager = (ActivityManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // For SDK version 23 and above.
        return activityManager.getLockTaskModeState()
            != ActivityManager.LOCK_TASK_MODE_NONE; 
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // When SDK version >= 21. This API is deprecated in 23.
        return activityManager.isInLockTaskMode();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: isInLockTaskMode is now deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isInLockTaskMode%28%29 Use getLockTaskModeState() instead.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Worked perfectly

Comment: Can this be used after you restart the activity using startActivity?